# Is there a link to "What topics can I ask about here"?

Tags: support

I asked a question, and was told it's not on-topic for this stack. That's all right.

Since then I've been using that response to find the link to "https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic" to get to the list of what actually *is* on topic.

Surely, there must be a link available from the front page that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask a question, you are presented with a link to [asking help](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on the right. That page contains link to the [on topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the proper context.

[image: Link to "Asking Help"]

Comment: Ah, I was just one click away, then. I don't think I ever noticed the topmost yellow box. O_o

Answer (score 4):

Apart from clicking through from the *[Ask a Question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)* page, the [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) is also available from the "help" button located on every page:

[image]